# How to insert an image list in the grouped items page befor each group?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8

I am currently developing a windows 8 application using XAML and C#. I developed the grouped items page that generates data groups dynamically. I have a list of social media icons that I need to put next to each group title but aligned on the left as shown in the screen shot!

When I add the list in the XAML Code, it is getting generated at the beginning of the first group! How can I have it for each group? any ideas? if anyone can provide me with the code that would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: Post your XAML efforts you did till now. We can not see any screen shot here.

Comment: http://test.gespacy.com/screenshot.png

Comment: And you want to have that list of icons before each group, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define GroupItemStyle in page resources section as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="GroupItemStyle1" TargetType="GroupItem">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="431*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="429*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderContent" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabIndex="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" IsTabStop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupItems}" Grid.Row="1" TabIndex="1" TabNavigation="Once" Grid.Column="1">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                        <TransitionCollection>
                                            <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                                            <ContentThemeTransition/>
                                            <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                                            <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                                        </TransitionCollection>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                </ItemsControl>
                                <!-- ***** Put your social icon list here **** Start-->
                                <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,194,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                <!-- ***** Put your social icon list here **** End -->
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Apply this style to GridView as:

```
<!-- Horizontal scrolling grid used in most view states -->
        <GridView
            x:Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Padding="116,137,40,46"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupItemStyle1}">
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                            .......
                  </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>
```

You will see the sample button before each group here - [image]

**UPDATE:**

Use following group styles: for example:

```
  <Style x:Key="GroupItemStyle3" TargetType="GroupItem">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="431*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="429*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderContent" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabIndex="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                            <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" IsTabStop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupItems}" Grid.Row="1" TabIndex="1" TabNavigation="Once" Grid.Column="1">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                    <TransitionCollection>
                                        <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                                        <ContentThemeTransition/>
                                        <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                                        <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                                    </TransitionCollection>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
                            </ItemsControl>


                            <StackPanel Background="Red" Grid.Row="1">
        <!-- ***** Put your social icon list here **** Start-->                 
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            <!-- ***** Put your social icon list here **** End -->
                            </StackPanel>

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

this will give you:

[image]

And this one will:

```
 <Style x:Key="GroupItemStyle2" TargetType="GroupItem">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="431*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="429*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderContent" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabIndex="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" IsTabStop="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupItems}" Grid.Row="1" TabIndex="1" TabNavigation="Once" Grid.Column="1">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                        <TransitionCollection>
                                            <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                                            <ContentThemeTransition/>
                                            <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                                            <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                                        </TransitionCollection>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                </ItemsControl>


                                <StackPanel  Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Red">
                                    <!-- ***** Put your social icon list here **** Start-->
                                    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                    <!-- ***** Put your social icon list here **** End -->
                                </StackPanel>

                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thx man that was very helpful! But there is a small issue, if u look at my screen shot, the buttons set is under the title not before it so if a small modification could solve this problem that would be great. My purpose of putting it under group title is that the same button repeated before different groups will have to take me to a different page, but I am afraid in yours they wont no?

Comment: How can I give different functionalities to same button repeated before each group depending on the group he belongs to?

Comment: How can I give different functionalities to same button repeated before each group depending on the group he belongs to? I need to target a specific button under for example group title 1 to take me to the next page but the button under group 2 should not!

Comment: You can bind meta data, e.g GroupId to button's Tag field. Get that Tag in button click event and do the processing accordingly.